# Java - Difference between javax.crypto.Mac and javax.crypto.Cipher?

Tags: cryptography, java, hmac

I would like to understand the difference between [javax.crypto.Mac](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/Mac.html) and [javax.crypto.Cipher](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html). Those two classes looks very similar (they have similar methods but those two classes do not inherits from each another).

1. What's the fundamental difference between those two classes ?
2. When should I use (or not use) Mac ?
3. When should I use (or not use) Cipher ?

Comment: The page it clearly states one is for message authentication codes the other is for encryption/decryption

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A [Message Authentication Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code) is for integrity. It computes, on some input message, a kind of "keyed checksum" that depends on the message and on the key. With knowledge of the key, the MAC can be verified to match a given message. Alterations are thus reliably detected.

A [Symmetric encryption algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encryption) is for confidentiality. It transforms a message into an unreadable sequence of bits; the encryption is reversible provided that the decryption key is known.

MAC do not ensure confidentiality; the message is kept as is, plainly readable. Encryption does not ensure integrity; alterations may go undetected. In properly applied cryptography, you need both. (But mind that this "properly" term is big.)

Comment: Very clear, thank you Tom Leek, I have a better understanding thanks to you (+1)